# Windows 7 File Transfer Speed Over Gigabit is Exceeding Expected Limits(!?)

Tags: windows-7, networking, gigabit-ethernet

I have two PCs and a network switch, all gigabit hardware. I transferred this ISO file between them and noticed the Windows copy dialog reporting faster rates than I expected:

[image]

**181 MB/s ?**

How could this be? Isn't the [theoretical maximum 125 MB/s](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gigabit-ethernet-bandwidth,2321-3.html)? Is this some kind of confusing mix of [Megabytes and Mebibytes](http://www.charlestonsw.com/the-difference-between-mib-and-mb/)? Could it be some cache optimization under the hood?

Comment: Let me get this straight... you're complaining that a file x-fer is going too fast?

Comment: @KronoS Not complaining, just wanting to learn.

Comment: My guess would be that Windows and/or your network drivers/card are successfully adding compression to file during transfer.  Maybe take the ISO and 7-zip it, to see how much smaller it gets (if at all)? Interestingly, it also still says "Calculating" which tells me it's confused or missing information, so the reported speeds are not based on actual (full) file knowledge, and are a 'best-guess'.

Comment: Also, I notice it says it's coming from "root", which OS is being copied from? (You only tagged "Windows-7")

Comment: Are you sure you were really copying it between the two at that moment, and not accidentally making a local copy?

Comment: Also, how long does it sustain this number? If a TCP segment was lost, a bunch of later segments (up to your TCP window size, which could be as much as, say, 2MiB) could be held in the TCP stack in the kernel, and then when the missing segment retransmit comes in, they could all be delivered to the app at once. So it could look like you got a dip followed by an impossibly high peak.

Comment: Transfer something 20 times bigger and show results...

Comment: @techie007 "root" is the name of the folder is it being copied from. The source machine is XP, the destination machine (the one reporting the speed in the dialog above) is Windows 7.

Comment: @Spiff I am sure - it was copying between the two machines, not making a local copy. I had a suspicion that something was going on similar to what you describe - data getting bunched up and then dumped out making the transfer look faster than what I expected.